# y with respect to t

Tags: word-choice, mathematics

In math, you say: **velocity** is the *rate of change* of **position** ***with respect to time***.

I'm looking for a better, mathematically correct way to say that, without using the phrase *with respect to* and *velocity is the time-derivative of position*.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this on Math.SE?

Comment: Since we are talking about *mathematically correct* ways, it should be noted that [velocity is not quite the same as speed](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/).

Comment: I wasn't aware anybody suggested otherwise... Velocity _is_ the rate of change of position with respect to time.  There's no reason a rate can't also be a vector.  dr/dt (r being a position vector) is a derivative and a derivative is, by definition, a rate.

Comment: I agree that it should be asked on math.SE, as it is asking for a _mathematically correct way_ to say a sentence. A mathematically correct way is different from a grammatically correct way.

Comment: I hate the expression __With respect to__.  It is fundamentally unclear.

Comment: I disagree. The asker is looking for a better way to say it in English, but, of course, the statement should remain mathematically correct, i.e. retain its current meaning.

Comment: @Jimi Oke:  I agree with your disagreement.  I think synonym requests would seem out of place on Math.SE...  Math-related or not.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, what is unclear about "with respect to?"  You have:  "<function name> with respect to <parameter name>" where <function name> is **always** the thing you're solving for and <parameter name> is **always** the independent variable.  Or, in the function f(x) = (...), f is <function name> and x is <parameter name>.

Comment: Or are you saying that usage/mechanics of it is clear but the origin/etymology is not?  (hence your employment of "fundamentally")

Comment: @Jimi Oke: _velocity_, in general use, is understood to mean _speed_ (e.g., _the tank shot backward at an incredible velocity_); it's only in physics that you say _the velocities of the emitted particles_. Look then at the mathematical concept of vector, and see the meaning of _vector_ outside mathemathics (see _the vector of the disease_, for example).

Answer (score 6):

I would just say *over*:

> An object's velocity is the change in its position over time.

Which is a natural expression of the derivative *dx*/*dt*.

Comment: +1 That's how I (and my fellow students) tend to say it.

Comment: It's _true_ but not synonymous with the original statement.  The "with respect to" means that position is a function of time.  Or, in other words, the independent variable in the function is time.  I make this distinction because you can't substitute "over" in place of "with respect to" in most cases... only this one.  For instance, if I have f(x)=3x^2, you could say "I defined F with respect to x".  You would not say, however, "I defined F over x."

Comment: N.B. In mathematics, "dx/dt" is usually read "dx by dt", though, not "over" (which is reserved for actual fractions).

Comment: ...For the record, I've never heard "dx by dt." I don't think I've seen it in a textbook either. I generally just say/ hear "dx dt." ....And actually I have heard "A function, f, is defined over x." Weird.

Comment: My Calc. teacher tells us (present tense because I'm taking Calc. 4  this semester) to read 1st order DE's as "dx, dt" and 2nd order DE's as "d-squared x, dt-squared" and partial differentials as "partial x, partial t," etc.

Comment: You don't say "over" because they aren't actual fractions.  The whole "separable ODEs" thing is only a convenient mechanism for skipping a few steps.  You're not actually separating them because they aren't actually fractions.

Comment: @advs89: When I posted this answer, I knew someone was going to bring that up (but I'm glad you did). I'm with @kitukwfyer on this one, though: I've *only* ever heard "dx dt", and I *have* heard "f defined over x". Regardless, saying *over* is *reasonably* correct mathematically, in a number of senses, and is perfectly correct in normal English. You can treat it as short for *over the course of* if you like.

Comment: Is _change in its position over time_ making any reference to the velocity as vector?

Comment: @kiamlaluno:  It can be.  In one-dimensional motion (moving along a straight line) your initial position could be x = 3 ft (from the origin) and your final position could be x = -3 ft (from the origin) and so you moved backwards six feet.  Therefore the change in position is negative six feet and if you did that in one second, your velocity would be -6 ft/s.  Speed can never be negative.  (because negative implies direction)  so in that scenario, _change in position over time_ is a vector.  (i.e. velocity)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could say "with relation to" or in some cases "as a function of". I'm not quite sure what's wrong with "with respect to" in this case, though.

Comment: +1:  yes, "as a function of" is the only thing I can think of that can be substituted for "with respect to."  I also agree that there is nothing wrong with "with respect to" as long as you know what it means.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> Velocity is the rate of change of position *with* time.

or possibly

> An object's velocity is the amount by which its position changes in a given time.

Answer (score 0):

I would say *velocity is the rate at which an object moves*, or *velocity is the measurement of the rate and direction of change in position of an object*.

Comment: I think this definition is a more accurate description of speed rather than velocity. Velocity has a direction component (location change), whereas speed is purely the rate.

Comment: The speed is the scalar component of the velocity; I don't think it is possible to explain the concept of vector in few words.

Comment: @kiamlaluno:  I believe he was agreeing with you.  He was saying that _your_ definition is better than the others.

Comment: @advs89: I think he is saying that I gave the definition of speed, not velocity.

Comment: Speed, velocity, flow rate with respect to time, growth rate with respect to time... anything other than WRT!

Comment: @kiamlaluno:  No, you're right.  After reading the comment again and viewing the edit history I see what you mean.  I think it's a little pedantic, though, to say that it's not velocity simply because you left out the word "direction."  Velocity is still the rate of a change of position of an objection.  Speed is just the absolute value of velocity.  (or qualitatively, it's the magnitude of the velocity without regard for direction)

Answer (score 0):

Ok how about **as**?

Velocity is the *rate of change* of distance **AS TIME** changes.

Say we have the volume of a cone

[image]

Then say we take the partial derivative *with respect to cone radius*.

[image]

Then we could say the *rate of change* of that volume **AS radius** changes, is that equation.