# About the words "Speed" and "Velocity"

Tags: etymology, history

[Physics guys](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/663802/what-was-the-need-to-introduce-the-term-velocity) closed these questions so I am here

From our daily experiences we know that whenever a body is moving with certain speed, it is always associated with a certain direction. How can you move and do not have any direction?

So my question is why did we introduce the term velocity? We could have considered Speed as a vector quantity and its magnitude- a rate, as a scalar quantity. In this case, speed will be a complete definition specifying both magnitude (i.e. rate, scalar) and its direction. This looks more intuitive and aligned with day-to-day human experience.

Then why we introduced a new term velocity? I would like to know the philosophy behind this!

There is [a question on speed vs velocity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/velocity-vs-speed), but it's not answering my question.

Comment: In some (many) contexts direction is irrelevant, only the speed matters. E.g., if you are driving your car around a bend your velocity is constantly changing but your speed is not. So in my view speed *without* direction is more intuitive and aligned with day-to-day human experience.

Comment: It's common for sciences to use a distinct term with a specific definition while common usage has many meanings for a word. Sometimes scientists do use the same word with a narrower meaning (e.g. "fruit" in biology or "space" in geometry) but often that is confusing because it's not clear whether the scientific sense or some general sense of the word is meant. Despite what the physics guys say, this is more a question about physics than language because it hinges on how velocity is used in physics and what it means, which isn't the same as what speed means in general English.

Comment: I'm not really clear on the precise question. Are you asking why the specific word "speed" is used for the scalar measurement and "velocity" for the vector, rather than using "rate" for the scalar and "speed" for the vector? (This is a matter of etymology and history of science, rather than philosophy.) Or do you have some question about physics (e.g. what are vectors and scalars, or how are velocity and speed used differently in physics?), or about how words can mean different but related things?

Answer (score 1):

If you drive around aimlessly starting and finishing at home, your average [speed](https://www.lexico.com/definition/speed) might be 30 but your average [velocity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574534/about-the-words-speed-and-velocity) 0.